# Angular2 binding Control to form input

Tags: typescript, angular

I just started learning angular2 and faced the problem. Below are some snippets from my code. Component looks like this:

```
export class MyClass{
...
model:MyVO = null;
...
_priority: Control;
...

constructor(){
    this.model = new MyVO(...);
    this._priority= new Control('', Validators.minLength(3));
    ...
}
```

And in my html code:

```
<input id="_priority" name="_priority" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model._priority" ngControl="_priority" #spy>
```

The problem is: the validator seems to be not binded. I spy on the class name, and when I change the value of this input, I can see that it gets ng-dirty, ng-touched etc, but still it says it's ng-valid. Doesn't matter if my input is 5 char-long or 1-char long. Any tips, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ngFormControl` instead in your HTML template:

```
<input id="_priority" name="_priority"
       type="text" class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="model._priority"
       [ngFormControl]="_priority" #spy>
```

The `ngControl` directive is only to declare inline controls.

The article could give you more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/11/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-1/

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot!! Having a hard time learning it, so many outdated sources around

Comment: Great! You're welcome! Yes the framework is still in beta so things can evolve a bit...

Comment: Thank you, will take a look for sure!